# SharePoint Foundation 2010 Document Library Pager

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to implement a better pager in my document libraries. I want to do one of two things. a) override the current pager that is pretty useless and doesn't indicate how many pages exist with something that provides better navigation, or b) write a web part that is very similar to the standard Telerik pager where you have a drop down selection to go to the page you want with a goto first and goto last as well as goto next etc. I would like to be able to place this control at the top and bottom of the Document Library.

Note that I can't use the Telerik SPDataGrid or SPList webparts as they use the taxonomy.dll which is not part of SharePoint Foundation. I have tried this already and I know it works in Standard or Enterprise but not Foundation, which is something that Telerik don't advertise.

If anyone can point me in the right direction on this where I can find code examples etc, I would be most grateful. I have searched high and low for this but not come across a solution as yet.

Thanks 
Dave

UPDATE:
This is the sort of Pager I am looking to create. This one is from an asp.net web application I wrote a couple of years ago using Infragistics controls.

[image: Document Library Pager]

Answer (score 1):

I would try a DataVew web part if possible. You can build these using SharePoint Designer 2010 and it supports filtering, paging and more. Furthermore, if you don't like the webpart SPDesigner produces you can try editing the xslt that's used to produce the webpart.

Here is a [tutorial](http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-sharepoint-2010-data-view-web.html)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you will not succeed with "custom pages" because of the CAML limitations. Either you will have lack of performance with custom pager or nice performance with standard pager.

I wouldn't recommend spending time for that task.